# Not Sure That I Successfully Git Pushed to a forked Repository

Tags: git, github

I forked a project on the GitHub and cloned that project to my local laptop.  I added some code to one of the project files and pushed the project to a GitHub "fork"ed repository.  I got a message saying **Everything up-to-date** back in the Git Bash command window.

I am not sure that the "push" was successful.  How do I find my code under the GitHub "forked" repository?  I have gone to the GitHub and signed in. I went to My_GitHub_UserName/Project_Name, I saw the project maintainer's code, I did not see my added code.  How do I know that the "push" is successful?  Thanks.

I did below:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin https://{github_username}:{github_password}@github.com/{github_username}/vlerdas-subscribe.git
$ git push origin master
```

The Git bash prompted: **Everything up-to-date**.

Comment: Why did you remove the origin and add it back? The cloned repo should have already had the origin set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: When you fork a project on GitHub, you essentially clone their git repo into your GitHub account. When you clone that, make a change and push, it goes to your fork, not the original maintainers repository.